# Multiple Regex Pattern with different formats

Tags: c#, regex

I have expression like this and I want match only digits inside the parenthesis just after from totalamount and minamount

```
"test test test test totalamount(32604) > 0m)"
"test test test test totalamount(32604, 13456) > 0m)"
"test test test test minamount(32604) > 0m)"
"test test test test minamount(32604, 34677, 12345) > 0m)"
```

So if I could have the right pattern my output should be

```
1- 32604
2- 32604, 13456
3- 32604
4- 32604, 34677, 12345





Regex regex = new Regex(@"(totalamount)\((\d*)(\,\d*)");
Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"(totalamount)\((\d*)(\d*)");
Regex regex3 = new Regex(@"(minamount)\((\d*)(\,\d*)");
Regex regex4 = new Regex(@"(minamount)\((\d*)(\d*)");

return regex.Match(expression).Success ? regex.Match(expression) : 
                   regex2.Match(expression).Success ? regex2.Match(expression):
                   regex3.Match(expression).Success ? regex3.Match(expression) :
                   regex4.Match(expression).Success ? regex4.Match(expression) : null;
```

Here is my solution but thats the worst solution I think there must be better way to match my case. Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Do you mean a "better solution" is: single regex pattern? If not, please, be more specific.

Comment: yeap single regex pattern absolutely be the better solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution:

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>()
                {
                "test test test test totalamount(32604) > 0m)",
                "test test test test totalamount(32604, 13456) > 0m)",
                "test test test test minamount(32604) > 0m)",
                "test test test test minamount(32604, 34677, 12345) > 0m)"
                };

string pattern = @"(?<=(?:total|min)amount\(|\G(?!^)[ ,]*)\d+";
var result = ls.SelectMany(s =>
            Regex.Matches(s, pattern).Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m=>Convert.ToInt32(m.Value)))
               .ToList();
```

Returns (`List<int>`):

```
32604 
32604 
13456 
32604 
32604 
34677 
12345
```

Comment: Thank you, @MehmetErenYener.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution with a single regex pattern, using alterations:

```
(?<=(total|min)(amount)\()\d*((\, )*\d*)*
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the previous two solutions need look-arounds, but here is a simple one without them:

```
(total|min)amount\(([\d,\s]+)\)
```

This will match the argument list and store it in capture group `$2` which is accessed via the `Groups` property of a `Match` at index `2`.

Example:

```
var expressions = new []
{
    "test test test test totalamount(32604) > 0m)",
    "test test test test totalamount(32604, 13456) > 0m)",
    "test test test test minamount(32604) > 0m)",
    "test test test test minamount(32604, 34677, 12345) > 0m)"
};


var numbers = new Regex(@"(total|min)amount\(([\d,\s]+)\)");

foreach (var expression in expressions)
    Console.WriteLine(numbers.Match(expression).Groups[2]);
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3iXF5